# UITableViewController with static cells: contentSize is {0, 0}

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, contentsize

[In my project](https://github.com/problame/CSNotificationView), I am adding a `UIView` to `UITableView` and adjust the `UIView`'s frame when the `contentOffset` of `UITableView` changes so that there is an illusion of a floating view above the `tableView`'s contents.

Users of the library now report that this tequnique does not work when the `UITableView` is created with **static cells through a storyboard**.

I did a bit of research on this and found that **in particular, the `tableView.contentSize`  becomes {0, 0}** as soon as you call `[tableView addSubview:...]`.

Apparently, this **is not a problem with dynamic cells**, but with static cells, the contentSize **stays {0, 0}** until you call `[tableView reloadData]`

Do you have any ideas why the UITableView(Controller) is behaving like this with static cells? And any ideas how to fix this without calling `[tableView reloadData]`?

Comment: I've the same problem but I'm not adding an `UIView`. I'm only using static cells. Only with `[tableView reloadData]` the correct size is reported. Did you found a solution for this problem? I also found out that I've to call `reloadData` also for dynamic cells. Another option would be `[self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];`

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `UITableViewController`. This means that the `view` property of the controller is the table view, and the table view is a bit touchy about adding other views.

Instead, you can go one of two routes: you can transform the controller into a plain `UIViewController`, add a table view and declare and implement the datasource and delegate methods for it. Then add your other view to the `view` rather than the table view.

You could also try to add the view to the `window`. This should work, but maybe you need to tweak the positioning if it should be relative to the visible view.

Comment: The problem is that the project is a CocoaPod that shall integrate into every view controller. The question is: why does it work with a dynamic tableView but not a static?

Comment: If you add to window it should integrate into every view controller.

Comment: I need to get behind the UINavigationController's navigationBar. Gonna post here if I find a solution.

Comment: wrapping it doesn't work. as i pointed out, it's a plugin-library.

Comment: Then you have to accept that your plugin-library cannot do it. Situations like this are one of the main arguments against 3rd party libraries. You have to code less, but you give up flexibility.

Comment: How about swizzling `setContentSize` to no-op before adding the subview, then swizzle it back?

Comment: Swizzling is always a little creepy to me. Thanks to everyone for your answers anyway ;)